# Call SP_RENAME via sp_executesql: how (and why) do I get the 'N' in front?

Tags: sql-server

Newbie here.  I am trying to use `sp_executesql` to call `SP_RENAME` so that I can rename a column according to a variable that is set differently with every repetition through a WHILE loop.  However, I'm stuck on how to get the `N` at the beginning of the call to end up included in the execution (and, frankly, I don't understand why it needs to be there, either).

So, if I write the code this way, it works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Db1.Temp1 (Col1 int, Col2 int)
EXEC sp_executesql N'SP_RENAME ''Db1.Temp1.Col1'', ''newname'', ''COLUMN''';
```

But if I try to use a variable to do the same command, I get an error (Msg 214... Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'):

```
CREATE TABLE Db1.Temp1 (Col1 int, Col2 int)
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SET @command = N'SP_RENAME ''Db1.Temp.Col1'', ''newname'', ''COLUMN''';
EXEC sp_executesql @command;
```

This is the same error I get if in that first block of code I drop the `N` in front of `SP_RENAME` - and, in fact, if I insert `PRINT @command` right after the `SET`, I can see that it's setting it without that `N`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The N is for unicode, and in the second example you're trying to store the unicode in a VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR. I am aware that there's no characters there that actually require unicode, but the N is telling it that it's unicode. You also don't need to have the N there in the first place.

Comment: Oh, and the error message tells you the issue if you use a VARCHAR instead of a NVARCHAR. The sp_executesql is expecting NTEXT/NCHAR/NVARCHAR and you're feeding it a VARCHAR

Comment: @ZLK: This completely fixed my problem and now I finally get what the heck it's doing, too.  Thank you!!  (How do I give you credit for answering it if it's not listed as an answer...?)